# SHAP Beeswarm Plot Interpretation

Tags: shap

I created a SHAP beeswarm plot, and I find it hard to interpret the effect of variables when high and low feature values are clustered together in smilingly random manner. Below are a couple of examples (green = high, blue = low ):

**Example 1**

[image]

**Example 2**

[image]

In Example 1, I can at least say that extremely high feature values have positive impact on the model output. However, I don't understand what to do with clusters of highs and lows particularly in Example 2. The only idea I have in mind is that there is the same number of high and low feature values with the same SHAP values.

So, is there more meaningful interpretations of such clusters?

Comment: Please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: This means one feature alone is not enough to separate effect of the feature on the outcome.

Comment: Bar importance and dependence plots are easier to read. (But take more space.)